# Solr upload schema.xml viw REST API

Tags: solr

I am probably blind,but I don't see it in the documentation. What is the correct url and curl request of update managed schema.xml file?

I had tried:

```
curl -X POST -d @schema.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://<SOLR>:8983/solr/<CORE>/schema/files/schema.xml

curl -X POST -d @schema.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://<SOLR>:8983/solr/<CORE>/schema

curl -X POST -d @schema.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://<SOLR>:8983/solr/<CORE>/schema/schema.xml
```

All with PUT method too.

version of Solr: 5.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no "replace the complete schema" [command for the Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API). The managed schema is updated based on a set of commands through the API:

> `POST /collection/schema`
>
> To add, remove or replace fields, dynamic field rules, copy field rules, or new field types, you can send a POST request to the /collection/schema/ endpoint with a sequence of commands to perform the requested actions. The following commands are supported:
>
> `add-field`: add a new field with parameters you provide.
>
> `delete-field`: delete a field.
>
> `replace-field`: replace an existing field with one that is differently configured.
>
> `add-dynamic-field`: add a new dynamic field rule with parameters you provide.
>
> `delete-dynamic-field`: delete a dynamic field rule.
>
> `replace-dynamic-field`: replace an existing dynamic field rule with one that is differently configured.
>
> `add-field-type`: add a new field type with parameters you provide.
>
> `delete-field-type`: delete a field type.
>
> `replace-field-type`: replace an existing field type with one that is differently configured.
>
> `add-copy-field`: add a new copy field rule.
>
> `delete-copy-field`: delete a copy field rule.

To do what you want, you probably want to replace the managed-schema file yourself and then restart solr or reload the core yourself:

> *Why is hand editing of the managed schema discouraged?*
>
> The file named "managed-schema" in the example configurations may include a note that recommends never hand-editing the file.  Before the Schema API existed, such edits were the only way to make changes to the schema, and users may have a strong desire to continue making changes this way.
>   The reason that this is discouraged is because hand-edits of the schema may be lost if the Schema API described here is later used to make a change, unless the core or collection is reloaded or Solr is restarted before using the Schema API.  If care is taken to always reload or restart after a manual edit, then there is no problem at all with doing those edits.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started working with Solr-with-docker. I wanted to post my custom fields, schema and was looking at options. However, I couldn't post a complete schema, but I could extend @matsLindh answer and used -d to post a file containing list of commands.

I saved the commands in a file

> extended-schema.json

```
{
    "add-field": [{
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string",
            "indexed": true,
            "stored": true,
            "multiValued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "other-name-1",
            "type": "string",
            "indexed": true,
            "stored": true,
            "multiValued": false
        }
    ],
    "add-copy-field": {
        "source": "other-name-*",
        "dest": "_text_"
    }
}
```

then, posted to the core's schema using v1 API as

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d @"${CORE_SCHEMA_FILE}" ${CORE_SCHEMA_URL}

curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d @extended-schema.json "http://localhost:8983/solr/${CORE}/schema?commit=true"
```

This saves me from running multiple posts and avoid logging into the terminal as I am running it via entrypoint from docker compose.